# iPhone/Objective-C - Problem with UIButton reset within UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` within a custom `UITableViewCell`. I added this button in Interface Builder.

I then use the following code within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GenericCellButton";

    GenericCellButton *cell = (GenericCellButton *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (GenericCellButton *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    [cell.inviteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(inviteButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.inviteButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    // This statement doesn't get called...?
    if ([cell.inviteButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Please Wait"]) {
        [cell.inviteButton setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.inviteButton setTitle:@"Please Wait" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }
  ...
```

This is the `followTapped:` method:

```
- (void)followTapped:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button setEnabled:NO];
    [button setTitle:@"Please Wait" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

    // I then call a service method that then fires off a callback method that refreshes the `tableView`. This changes the button text to "Following".
}
```

Everything is working just fine in terms of saving the record.

The problem is that before the callback method is fired; if the user scrolls the visible cell out of view before the `tableView` is refreshed, it's resetting the button back to "Follow" instead of "Please Wait", which means if they tap the "Follow" button again it causes issues in my database.

How can I stop that particular cell from refreshing before the `tableView` is reloaded if it is scrolled out of view? I tried adding some logic in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that checks for whether the button text is "Please Wait", but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. It's still resetting back to "Follow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)followTapped:(id)sender 
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
[button setEnabled:NO];
[button setTitle:@"Please Wait" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

selectedIndex = indexPath.row; //create this variable in .h file 

// I then call a service method that then fires off a callback method that refreshes the `tableView`. This changes the button text to "Following".
 }
```

Now

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GenericCellButton";

GenericCellButton *cell = (GenericCellButton *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (GenericCellButton *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

[cell.inviteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(inviteButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.inviteButton setTag:indexPath.row];

// This statement doesn't get called...?
if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
{
    [cell.inviteButton setEnabled:NO];
    [cell.inviteButton setTitle:@"Please Wait" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
```

...

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how `selectedIndex = indexPath.row; //create this variable in .h` would work when we're outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: you just need to pass the another argument like :
(void)followTapped:(id)sender AndIndex((NSIndexPath *)indexPath then it would work...

Comment: so when u click on the button u have to pass the current row index which hold that button to that method

Comment: Got it working with minor adjustments, but you led me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: in sort u just have to remember that which row you've previously selected. and when table view recycle the cells then tell the table view to treat this cell (you previously button clicked) in another way.. that's it...

Answer (score 2):

The `UITableView` class is usually configured to recycle cells. If you configure it like this, e.g. by following the template provided by Apple, then it's not going to work to use the cell to preserve any state information. The normal approach is to recover whatever state you need in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and apply it to the cell. So get your `followTapped:` method to save the state and then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` apply `[button setEnabled:NO];` and `[buttonSetTitle:@"Please wait"];` according to the saved state. Hope that helps (and that I've not missed the point of the question.)

Comment: I do actually set a tag on the button within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I'll try saving the state some how and see how I go from there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: See my updated question code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I'm trying to detect for "Please Wait" within a cell and set it to be disabled, but it doesn't seem to be working.